# Insert key value to nested dictionaries in list by index

Tags: python

Has list with nested dictionaries:

```
k = [{'width_min': 0, 'width_max': 300, 'height_min': 0, 'height_max': 65535},
    {'width_min': 301, 'width_max': 600, 'height_min': 0, 'height_max': 65535},
    {'width_min': 601, 'width_max': 65535, 'height_min': 0, 'height_max': 65535}]
```

And key map:

```
keymap = {
    'width_min': 'minWidth',
    'width_max': 'maxWidth',
    'height_min': 'minHeight',
    'height_max': 'maxHeight',
}
```

Trying to create new list with the same dictionaries, but different key names:

```
new_data = []
for i, x in enumerate(k):
    for k, v in x.items():
        new_data.insert(i, {keymap[k]: v})
print('---> new_data:', new_data)
```

Prints:

```
new_data: [{'maxHeight': 65535}, {'maxHeight': 65535}, {'maxHeight': 65535}, 
{'minHeight': 0}, {'maxWidth': 65535}, {'minWidth': 601}, {'minHeight': 0},   
{'maxWidth': 600}, {'minWidth': 301}, {'minHeight': 0}, {'maxWidth': 300},   
{'minWidth': 0}]
```

how can I update nested dictionary by index instead of creating new dictionaries?
Expect array:

```
k = [{'minWidth': 0, 'maxWidth': 300, 'minHeight': 0, 'maxHeight': 65535},
    {'minWidth': 301, 'maxWidth': 600, 'minHeight': 0, 'maxHeight': 65535},
    {'minWidth': 601, 'maxWidth': 65535, 'minHeight': 0, 'maxHeight': 65535}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over your list `k` and use dictionary comprehension to get the new keynames from `keymap`:

```
k = [{'width_min': 0, 'width_max': 300, 'height_min': 0, 'height_max': 65535},
{'width_min': 301, 'width_max': 600, 'height_min': 0, 'height_max': 65535},
{'width_min': 601, 'width_max': 65535, 'height_min': 0, 'height_max': 65535}]
keymap = {
'width_min': 'minWidth',
'width_max': 'maxWidth',
'height_min': 'minHeight',
'height_max': 'maxHeight',
}
k = [{keymap.get(a, a):b for a, b in i.items()} for i in k]
```

Output:

```
[{'minWidth': 0, 'maxHeight': 65535, 'minHeight': 0, 'maxWidth': 300}, {'minWidth': 301, 'maxHeight': 65535, 'minHeight': 0, 'maxWidth': 600}, {'minWidth': 601, 'maxHeight': 65535, 'minHeight': 0, 'maxWidth': 65535}]
```

Comment: and for the very cautious, maybe `[{keymap.get(a, a)..`

Comment: I would _avoid_ the `keymap.get` since that would hide a potential error in the input data.  Fail Fast!